# Getting internal error: BuildFrameworkTcImports: no resolution of 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0' with ionide in VSCode

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

Getting this internal error in PROBLEMS window and Auto Complete is not working.

```
file: 'file:///startup'
    severity: 'Error'
    message: 'internal error: BuildFrameworkTcImports: no resolution of 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a''
    at: '1,1'
    source: ''
```

VSCode version : 1.10.1

Comment: A link to GitHub: https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/389